# Google chart (javascript)- difficulty in ascending/descending for close numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, line, sequential

please take a look at my project:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwt3ccoe/

This is my data array as you see in that page:

```
      ['E6', 12],
      ['E5', 13],
      ['E4', 14],
      ['E3', 15],
      ['E2', 16],
      ['E1', 17]
```

As I predicted, this line should be drawn upper than what I see.

Surprisingly, if I change the values like this:

```
      ['E6', 5],
      ['E5', 6],
      ['E4', 7],
      ['E3', 8],
      ['E2', 9],
      ['E1', 10]
```

line chart is exactly as I expect. (increasing numbers must be up to -I think- 15!)

if I change my array to something like this:

```
      ['E6', 15],
      ['E5', 30],
      ['E4', 22],
      ['E3', 5],
      ['E2', 18],
      ['E1', 16]
```

it also works perfect.

It seems that problem accrues when numbers are sequential!

try the following array to see:

```
      ['E6', 30],
      ['E5', 29],
      ['E4', 28],
      ['E3', 27],
      ['E2', 26],
      ['E1', 25]
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find out the cause of this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a problem with 
height: "100%"
When I change it to px something happens

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself :)

the problem caused due to not defining the correct height and minimum value.

I fixed it this way:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/154z0wvt/1/][1]
```

I hope it is useful for someone.